# TYPO3 suggest wizard, search in substring

Tags: php, autocomplete, typo3, autosuggest, typo3-tca

I use the suggest wizard in TYPO3 backend.

The following code is in the tca:

```
'tx_db_colors' => array (
'exclude' => 0,
'label' => 'Farbe',
    'config' => array (
        "type" => "group",
        "allowed" => "tx_db_colors",
        "foreign_table" => "tx_db_colors",
        "internal_type" => "db",
        "size" => 1,
        "minitems" => 0,
        "maxitems" => 1,
        'items' => array(array('', ''),),
        'wizards' => array(
            'suggest' => array(
                'type' => 'suggest',
            ),
        ),
    )
),
```

Is there a solution, to get matched records in substring of the label, not from scratch?

**Example:**

> The records label is named '**coffee black**'
>
> When I type 'co' into the search field, the record will be shown.
>
> 'blac' won't match to any record.

Is this possible to find this record, when I type in a substring? Else I have to extend the autocompletion. TYPO3 Core, yuk! :-)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please search the bugtracker (for 4.7). I am not sure if it has been implemented, but I am sure I saw such a change request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours, I found the solution.
You have to write the tca like this:

```
'tx_db_colors' => array (
    'exclude' => 0,
    'label' => 'Farbe',
    'config' => array (
        "type" => "group",
        "allowed" => "tx_db_colors",
        "foreign_table" => "tx_db_colors",
        "internal_type" => "db",
        "size" => 1,
        "minitems" => 0,
        "maxitems" => 1,
        'items' => array(array('', ''),),
        'wizards' => array(
            'suggest' => array(
                'type' => 'suggest',
                'default' => array(
                    'searchWholePhrase' => 1
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
),
```

Just add

```
'default' => array(
    'searchWholePhrase' => 1
),
```

into the 'suggest' array.

Comment: You can mark this answer as correct - then the question is removed from the unanswered items list.